# My code can not be compiled, I have no idea why

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, return-value

I have some lines of code, for which I get errors, but I don't know why.

```
T2 at(T1 p1, T1 p2) const
{
  return my_map[p1][p2];
}


T2 operator() (T1 p1, T1 p2) const
{
  return my_map[p1][p2];
}
```

and the code being in the main:

```
if ( max * max == relation.size() &&
       1462 == distances.at( "City1", "City2" ) &&
       1826 == cdist.at( "City3", "City1" ) )
{

  XY = cdist.size() -
                cdist.at( "City1", "City2" ) +
                distances( "City3", "City2" );

}
```

(Where cdist is the same object as distances, but is a const.)

The error might be simple, but I am getting really tired of this. (Error: passing '..' as 'this' argument of '..' discards qualifiers.)

Comment: You need to show all the relevant declarations, etc, and which line of code is throwing the error?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: lol. Good luck getting answers. We're not psychic. Supply meaningful code.

Comment: Pretend you were someone else trying to solve your own problem. Would *you* be able to identify the problem with what you have given above?

Comment: Show s.th. reproducible (e.g. try compiling your sample on [ideone](http://ideone.com/INdDnz) first)!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call `operator[]` on a const map.

Use `mapvariable.at(indexer).at(another_indexer)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting it's because `operator[]` on `std::map` is not a const operation. You probably need to use the `find()` method or the C++11 `at()` method instead.

Comment: c++11 added http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

Comment: @sehe: That's great for those who are up to C++11. And then it's a matter of how you want to be notified that what you asked for isn't there -- end iterator or exception.

Comment: in general, yes. But his code is using `return my_map[p1][p2];` which simply doesn't tolerate missing keys anyways :)